# change backgroundColor of FullCalendar event (v4)

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I'm trying to implement a 'selected event' behavior in FullCalendar v4 but no luck.
The behavior I want is:

- When clicking a event, it's color changes and the event becomes the selected event
- When clicking another event, the previous selected event changes color to default color and the newly clicked event becomes the selected event and changes color
- When clicking outside an event, the selected event becomes null and all visible events get the default color.

The first problem is to change the background color of the clicked event but I don't succeed.

The FullCalendar v4 docs are a bit ambiguous regarding backgroundColor.
I tried following methods (react example):

In the setup I've put

```
const calendar = new Calendar(this.calRef.current, {
    ...
    eventClick: this.eventClick
    ...
}
```

The first method uses the setProp method as described [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Event-setProp)

```
eventClick = (info) => {
    info.event.setProp('backgroundColor', 'red')
}
```

This doesn't work though

The second method uses element styling as described [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick)

```
eventClick = (info) => {
    info.el.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```

This doesn't work either

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: But I can't see any problem with your second method, it should work fine: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/zQXmWr?&editable=true&editors=001

Comment: If you still have an issue, can you make a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which we could use to actually see your problem happening?

Comment: Thanks ADyson for answering so quickly. I discovered that I also had a class applied to the events in which I had a backgroundColor !important property. So the color didn't get overruled. What should I do? Answer my own question?

Comment: I don't understand why the first method doesn't work though. The docs clearly mention that calling `setProp`will rerender the event!

Comment: It depends if you think that fact would be of interest to others who want to work with fullCalendar. I'd suggest it probably isn't, since it's very specific to your circumstances. So maybe the best thing is just to delete the question

Comment: Just tested and now method 1 indeed works also. I wonder why my question has been downvoted.

Comment: Apologies, I hadn't realised setProp did that (haven't used v4 much, and such a thing wasn't a feature in v3). But you're right it does - see updated codepen: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/zQXmWr?&editable=true&editors=001 . Again I assume the reason it didn't work for you before was for the same reason - your separate class being applied in the CSS.

Comment: P.S. I didn't downvote you so I don't know. If you hover over the downvote button on any question you can see the reasons why downvotes are supposed to be given...but of course unfortunately you can never be sure whether any of those was actually the downvoter's real motive.

Comment: It's a bug from FullCalendar not fixed yet: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/4393